# Merging Turbine and Forecast Data Diagonally

Tags: time-series, dataframe, csv

I am trying to combine my main dataset, which is hourly data collected from a turbine, with forecast data. The forecast data is collected by calling an API every hour to get a new .csv file which is the forecast for the next 7 days every hour, from the time of collection.

My goal is to diagonally merge every .csv into my main dataset. I already have a way to get the associated filename and a I have boolean if said file exists since there are some missing forecasts. Below are some examples of the data, but there are columns I am leaving out so these data frames are huge.

***example of the main dataset***

| timestamp | InvPwr_kW | forecast_file | forecast_file_exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-14 15:00:00-05:00 | 0.8033946659 | file1.csv | TRUE |
| 2023-11-14 16:00:00-05:00 | 0.4556512312 | file2.csv | TRUE |
| 2023-11-14 17:00:00-05:00 | 0.1023946659 | file3.csv | TRUE |
| 2023-11-14 18:00:00-05:00 | 0.6556534534 | file4.csv | TRUE |

***example of a forecast data file, (this one would be file1.csv)***

| timestamp | windSpeed_mph |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-14 15:00:00-05:00 | 10 |
| 2023-11-14 16:00:00-05:00 | 11 |
| 2023-11-14 17:00:00-05:00 | 12 |
| 2023-11-14 18:00:00-05:00 | 13 |

***end goal***

The first row of the forecast file would be merged with the same row as its filename in the main dataset with _0h since it was the forecast for that hour. The next row of the forecast data would be in the next row of the main dataset with _1h since it was the forecast for that time one hour ago and so on.

| timestamp | InvPwr_kW | forecast_file | forecast_file_exists | windSpeed_0h | windSpeed_1h | windSpeed_mph_2h | windSpeed_mph_3h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-14 15:00:00-05:00 | 0.8033946659 | file1.csv |  | 10 |  |  |  |
| 2023-11-14 16:00:00-05:00 | 0.4556512312 | file2.csv |  |  | 11 |  |  |
| 2023-11-14 17:00:00-05:00 | 0.1023946659 | file3.csv |  |  |  | 12 |  |
| 2023-11-14 18:00:00-05:00 | 0.6556534534 | file4.csv |  |  |  |  | 13 |

***my attempt***

Here's a snippet of my attempt so far. Currently, I get no output from this. It takes too long and crashes VS Code. I know that using .itterows in a data frame is very slow, but I'm not sure how else to get around it.

```
#for each row in frames
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #if the forecast file exists
    if row['forecast_file_exists'] == True:

            #error catching
            try:
                #read the file
                filename = row['forecast_file']
                forecast_df = pd.read_csv('./forecast-data-processed/' + filename, dtype=forecast_column_types, parse_dates=['timestamp'])

                #merge the forecast in
                suffix = f"_{index}h"
                df = pd.merge(df, forecast_df, how='left', on='timestamp', suffixes=('', suffix))

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing {filename}:")
                print(f"Error details: {e}")
                exit
```

Thank you for reading and I appreciate any advice on this. Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2):

[Hadley](https://hadley.nz) and I offer this critique of your approach:

Your data is messy.
It's time to [tidy](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-tidy.html) it up!

---

Consider these grades on a monthly spelling test:

| student | Jan. | Feb. | Mar. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 89 | 91 | 92 |
| Bob | 79 | 84 | 85 |

This is messy data, very inconvenient for analysis.
What you really want is this:

| time | student | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | Alice | 89 |
| 2023-01 | Bob | 79 |
| 2023-02 | Alice | 91 |
| 2023-02 | Bob | 84 |
| 2023-03 | Alice | 92 |
| 2023-03 | Bob | 85 |

Now we have a compound
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key#Design)
of `(time, student)` mapping to one or more attributes,
and we can conveniently pick out time ranges,
compute aggregate statistics, and so on.

---

Your "end goal" diagonal that involves `windSpeed_mph_3h` is the same thing.
You want the wind speed forecast data organized
with a PK of `(time, delta)` mapping to a forecast windspeed.

For the row that has `delta` hours of `0`,
it's showing an *actual* measured windspeed,
a historic fact of what was observed to happen at that time.
Other rows listing the same time will have some non-zero `delta`,
representing a forecast made that many hours ahead of time.

Recommend you store the inverter power in KW in a
[separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) RDBMS table,
and then JOIN against that when you need to combine things.
You might find it convenient to CREATE VIEW,
in order to record a JOIN query that you often use.

## external storage

> ... takes too long and crashes VS Code.

It sounds like you're exhausting internal storage,
you're exceeding the amount of installed RAM.

A relational database is a terrific way to deal with
such challenges. A table index, such a primary key,
is an on-disk datastructure that lets us navigate
large datasets very rapidly, and supports fast JOIN operations.
Postgres and MariaDB are excellent options, but even the
very simple sqlite, bundled with python's standard libraries,
would be a big step up from your current approach.
Remember to put time indexes on your tables.
Pandas offers great support for
[reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) and
[writing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
table data to an RDBMS.

Comment: Hey Hadley, thanks for the response. I don't have much experience with databases, and ultimately the data will be used for machine learning so I would like it to be accessible. Do you think using a database could be limited for the future of my project?

Also, what sort of SQL command would give me the result I'm looking for?  Any tips for making this work with just dataframes so that I could test it on a smaller scale?

Answer (score 1):

You want to reshape your forecast file. You could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.10.0/installing-miller/) and run

```bash
mlr --csv cat -n then \
put '$n=$n-1;$n="windSpeed_".string($n)."h"' then \
reshape -s n,windSpeed_mph then \
unsparsify input.csv > output.csv
```

to get

```
+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| timestamp                 | windSpeed_0h | windSpeed_1h | windSpeed_2h | windSpeed_3h |
+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2023-11-14 15:00:00-05:00 | 10           |              |              |              |
| 2023-11-14 16:00:00-05:00 |              | 11           |              |              |
| 2023-11-14 17:00:00-05:00 |              |              | 12           |              |
| 2023-11-14 18:00:00-05:00 |              |              |              | 13           |
+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Some notes:

- `cat -n` to add a field with a progressive id counter (1 based)
- `put '$n=$n-1;$n="windSpeed_".string($n)."h"'` to transform to zero-based, and create your desired field name
- `reshape -s n,windSpeed_mph` to apply the reshape you want

But please pay attention to [@j-h answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/126378/65128).

Comment: Thanks for answering! So you're suggesting that I reshape forecast files and then simply concat the two? And I am working to set up a database now...

Comment: @EliOrians I am not suggesting anything to you. But I have shown you how to accomplish the most important part of your request. I hope my answer is useful to you

Comment: @EliOrians What solution did you use? Did it work?

Comment: Not at a final solution yet. I used your suggestion of reshaping the forecast data so it is ready to be merged directly into my main dataset, but I did it using pandas since I'm more familiar with that. However, when trying to merge the forecasts into my main dataset (using pandas pd.merge) I get this error; "'method' object is not subscriptable". I haven't had time to dig into this yet, but I'd appreciate further suggestions if you have them. I'll update once I figure it out as well.

Comment: @EliOrians I will use once again Miller to make the final simple join